# How do I notate the gradient with respect to an arbitrary parameter?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The gradient is:

$ \nabla y = \sum_{i=0}^N{\frac{\partial y}{\partial s_i}} \hat{e_i} $

where $\vec{s}$ is some space parameter.

I'd like to find and write down the value $\sum_{i=0}^N{\frac{\partial
    y}{\partial u_i}} \hat{e_i}$ for some value $\vec{u}$ instead.

Maybe there is some variation of the chain rule and some function $f$
that I can use so that I can notate the value as something like $
f\left(\nabla y, D \vec{u} \right) $ similar to how for a
one-dimensional derivative I can notate the derivative as
$\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{u}}$? One problem though with that kind of
notation is that $\dot{u}$ must not be equal to zero for
$\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{u}}$ to be necessarily the same as the
derivative or one must use limits to paper over the holes.

Comment: @Tryss I made a mistake in my notation and fixed it.